# Determining maximum valid setrecursionlimit value for Python

Tags: python, recursion

In the Python 2 documentation, the sys library contains the following (bolded part is my edit):

`sys.setrecursionlimit(limit)`

> Set the maximum depth of the Python interpreter stack to limit. This limit prevents infinite recursion from causing an overflow of the C stack and crashing Python.
>
> The highest possible limit is platform-dependent. A user may need to set the limit higher when she has a program that requires deep recursion **and a platform that supports a higher limit**. This should be done with care, because a too-high limit can lead to a crash.

What does this mean?  Is this just a general "make sure you have enough memory to handle the extra stack space" statement, or is there a specific "per stack frame" size that can be used to calculate the memory value required?  What happens to Python when it can't acquire the space?

Comment: _What happens to Python when it can't acquire the space?_ Quoting from your quote: _This limit prevents infinite recursion from causing an overflow of the C stack and crashing Python._ - you can safely assume CPython interpreter will "crash" - most likely it'll segfault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why let's find out:

```
me@host$ docker run -m 4MB --cpuset-cpus=0 -it --rm python:3.5.1
Python 3.5.1 (default, Dec  9 2015, 00:12:22)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys, struct
>>> maxint = 2 ** (struct.Struct('i').size * 8 - 1) - 1
>>> sys.setrecursionlimit(maxint)
>>> def goodbye_world():
...  goodbye_world()
...
>>> goodbye_world()
me@host$
```

Welp. Looks like it crashes Python. Pretty quickly, too, when you only give it 4MB of RAM.

Comment: This is a great example, but I don't really understand *everything* that's happening.  For instance, with a 64-bit machine + 64-bit Python, `struct.Struct('i').size` is 8, so that `maxint` is `(2 ** 63) - 1`.  But it isn't obvious to me why this is a good choice for setting a recursion limit. Can I assume that each recursion will only consume 1 i-unit (32/64 bit)? Why? Is this because each recursion only consumes one address in the memory?  Would you mind elaborating?  Thanks so much!

Comment: @MikeWilliamson it's only been a few years since I wrote this answer, so I don't truly remember why I used that value, but I *think* it's because that's the maximum addressable size for that architecture (so, a 64-bit number for a 64-bit system). I definitely wasn't suggesting that it's a good recursion limit (as the crash evidences). A good recursion limit is one that 1) your platform supports, and 2) allows you to do what you need. Sometimes 1 prevents 2.